# How to disable redirections in ktor-client

Tags: kotlin, httpclient, ktor

I am creating simple HTTP request with ktor-client (ApacheHttpClient engine)

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    engine {
        followRedirects = false
        this@HttpClient.expectSuccess = false
    }
}
```

and using it to submit a form

```
client.submitForm<HttpResponse>(
        url = "https://foo.com/login",
        formParameters = Parameters.build {
            append("_username", username)
            append("_password", password)
        })
```

In logs, I can see a correct response with 302-redirection which I want to get and obtain a cookie from it. But instead, I see that the client moves on and makes several more requests and finally fails with:

> io.ktor.client.features.SendCountExceedException: Max send count 20 exceeded

How can I completely disable 302-based redirections in ktor-client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ktor-client [follows redirects by default](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/features/http-redirect.html), to prevent infinite redirects use:

```
val client = HttpClient(HttpClientEngine) {
    followRedirects = false
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the correct spot to put `followRedirects = false`. I've put it into `engine`, but correct spot is higher.